# Ansible 'Become' zimbra user

Tags: bash, ansible, sudo, su, zimbra

When running a playbook with sudo escalation, what would the process be to get to this point?

> user > sudo -s > su zimbra > **zimbra cli**

As this is the only way to run commands in the Zimbra CLI

At the moment I have the following... I dont get any errors when running the playbook however nothing happens on the host side.

```
---
- hosts: mail
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo


  tasks:

  - name: Generate CSR
    become_user: zimbra
    command: zmcertmgr createcsr comm -new -keysize 4096 -digest sha512 -subject "/C="{{cert_c}}"/ST="{{cert_st}}"/L="{{cert_l}}"/O="{{cert_o}}"/OU="{{cert_ou}}"/CN="{{cert_cn}}"" "{{cert_alt}}"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorted it out....

Running Zimbra commands via Ansible requires the absolute path to be used:

```
---
- hosts: mail
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo


  tasks:

   - name: Generate CSR
     become_user: zimbra
     command: /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr createcsr comm -new -keysize 4096 -digest sha512 -subject "/C="{{cert_c}}"/ST="{{cert_st}}"/L="{{cert_l}}"/O="{{cert_o}}"/OU="{{cert_ou}}"/CN="{{cert_cn}}"" "{{cert_alt}}"
```

Comment: Was an example for any Zimbra command, but you are right...edited.

Comment: How is that you didn't get any error message ("*I dont get any errors when running the playbook*") when the executable could not be found?

Comment: I'm not sure why, I didn't dig too deep beyond adding a verbose tag on the playbook run. Without the full Zimbra command path It simply finished without any warnings/errors.